# Why does git wrap my log output in quotes?

Tags: bash, git

If I used the following command:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%ad %s%d"
```

the output is:

> Tue Apr 26 11:29:24 2016 +0000 Updated configuration

If I do the following:

```
SIMPLE='--pretty=format:"%ad %s%d"'
git log $SIMPLE
```

then the output is as follows:

> "Tue Apr 26 11:29:24 2016 +0000 Updated configuration"

I know that I can define `alias gitl='git log --pretty=format:"%ad %s%d"'`. But it's just bugging me to know why git is doing this.

Why does the output appear in quotes when using the variable substitution approach?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with git to know; the first example has two dashes `--pretty=...` but the 2nd and 3rd examples have one dash. Are both acceptable?

Comment: @JeffSchaller That's a typo. Corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is because of some shell quoting specialties.

If you execute either of these (they are equivalent ways of quoting in the shell)

```
git log --pretty=format:'%ad %s%d'
git log '--pretty=format:%ad %s%d'
git log --pretty=format:%ad\ %s%d
git log --pretty=form'at:%ad %'s%d
git log --pretty=format:%ad" "%s%d
git log --pretty=format:"%ad %s%d"
```

`git` will get two arguments, the first being `log` and the second `--pretty=format:%ad %s%d`.

If you execute

```
SIMPLE='--pretty=format:"%ad %s%d"'
```

the variable `SIMPLE` will have the value `--pretty=format:"%ad %s%d"`, *including* the double quotes.

Now if we are in zsh and you execute

```
git log $SIMPLE
```

or in bash

```
git log "$SIMPLE"
```

`git` will see the second argument as `--pretty=format:"%ad %s%d"`. (If I execute `git log $SIMPLE` in bash I get an error because `git` gets three arguments: `log`, `--pretty=format:"%ad` and `%s%d"`).

So inside the variable you would not need the inner quotes (except if you want to pass it to `eval`).